# Query result different in APEX vs SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a weird situation and dont really know what is the issue.
I have a different query result between apex and sql developer. 
The schema is the same on 12c database.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a difference in your nls settings. Does your where clause include dates or numbers that have fractions?

Comment: What does "different query result" actually mean?

Comment: @OlafurTryggvason Good starting point, Yes i have dates in the where clause I will check that and let you know.

Comment: I would guess then that you are doing implicit conversions. Make sure all conversions of text to date are explicit

Comment: At the very least post the query you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

IN one calling function we were using USER for audit and audit column for username was 6 characters.

```
> So in :
> - SQL DEV : USER WAS returning the schema name with 6 digits, which is correct
> - IN Apex : USER Was ANONYMOUS , an exception was catch so we did not know where the problem is. 

  I just changed this with nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER) to solve the issue.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should not catch exceptions you can't handle sensibly. This is why the commonly-seen 'exception when others then ... do nothing useful' pattern is usually considered a bug.